# Why do brinjal change their color when they being cut? How to keep them not to change color?

Tags: vegetables, color

Why do brinjals (eggplant, aubergine) change their color(mostly black or brown) when they being cut? How to keep them not to change their color after cutting them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aubergine change colour because they are oxidizing, potatoes are in the plant family(night shades)   and turn brown too.  The best way to prevent browing is to immerse in water as soon as they are cut. Rubbing them with oil will help too, but not as much as  soaking them in water.

Comment: Placing aubergine slices in water sounds like a great way to make them super soggy.